# Invalid hook call for using useHistory, useLocation hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Display from './Components/Display';

export function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={Display} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**Display.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function History() {
  let history = useHistory(); // error saying invalid hook call
  let location = useLocation();
  console.log(history);
  return <h2>Hello Display</h2>;
}

export default History;
```

I am facing invalid hook calls on using those hooks.

This is my dependencies :

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
  "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
  "axios": "^0.19.2",
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
  "react-router": "^5.1.2",
  "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
  "redux": "^4.0.5"
}
```

Comment: you don't have react-router-dom in your dependency

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I solved the issue by adding resolutions in package .json

```
"resolutions": {
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Router component from react-router-dom without providing a custom history object.

You can either use BrowserRouter or provide a custom history prop

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Display from './Components/Display';

export  function App() {


  return (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Display } />
    <Router>
  )
}
```

Display.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function History() {
    let history = useHistory();
    let location = useLocation();
    console.log(history)
    return<h2>Hello Display</h2>
}

export default History
```

Comment: i tried even with BrowserRouter , still facing same issue

Comment: YOu were not invoking location function too. Please check that

Comment: I have the same issue. Using BrowserRouter did not fix the issue.

Comment: @blankface Do you have v16.8 or above of react and also v5.1 or above of react-router-dom

Comment: Yes for both. I am using create-react-app

Comment: @blankface please try and run npm ls react to see if by any change you have conflicting version of react in your code

Comment: it shows that i have only 1 version of react in the project

Comment: @blankface ok, please ask a new question with more details on your project and also mention the versions of each package

Comment: Fixed it. The issue was me using semantic-ui Popup, when I should've been using a Modal.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my react version to 16.14.0 and now it works. the react 17.0 seems to be broken with react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using React Element instead React Component, this was the reason why useHistory() hook was throwing an error.

Comment: the answer isn't very clear, could you elaborate this with some code please

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue while upgrading from React 16 to React 17. It is caused by "mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)". I upgraded all the dependencies and it started working.
Following list of dependencies worked for me.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10",
  "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
  "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.50",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
  "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.1.5",
  "formik": "^2.1.4",
  "loadjs": "^4.2.0",
  "lodash": "^4.17.15",
  "history": "^5.0.0",
  "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
  "pure-react-carousel": "^1.27.0",
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
  "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
  "yup": "^0.28.3"
}
```

PS: I was using "yarn workspaces" with multiple react projects. Each having different list of dependencies. I had to separate one project to make it work and reach this conclusion.

Comment: The version of react, react-router-dom is same as yours but still I am facing the issue.

Comment: I can confirm that these set of dependencies work. Try to check there aren't other react versions in your project. Also delete the "node_modules" & "package-lock.json" or "yarn.lock" and install again

Answer (score 0):

in my case , I used the useHistory in the event handlers .

when I remove  `let history = useHistory();` line of code from the event handlers , the problem solved.

There are some restrictions about how to use hooks in ReactJs.

Do not call Hooks in class components.

Do not call in event handlers.

Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect.

For more , you can read this [Invalid Hook Call Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

Comment: What are the version of the react and react-router-dom you are using

Comment: "react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today. Tried to find out the solutions here, but none of them worked.

At last, I just downgraded the version of "react-router-dom" from "5.3.0" to "5.2.0", and boom, its working fine.

The command for 5.2.0 is,

> yarn add react-router-dom@5.2.0

I'm using "react": "^17.0.2" and "react-dom": "17.0.2" with react-router-dom 5.2.0

This problem occurs whenever I add another package. After adding a package, it automatically upgrade the version. Then I have to downgrade it everytime. Stay careful whenever you install a package.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, VSCode had chosen the wrong import when I auto-imported. It was using the `useLocation` hook in `react-router` when it should've been using `react-router-dom`.